# How to select multiple rows to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
id name 
1  a    
2  b    
3  c    
4  d   
5  e
```

If I do `select name from tableTest where id = 1 or id = 2`, I got this:

```
name
a
b
```

But I want a result like this:

```
name_1   name_2 
a        b

-- 1, 2: Best: the value of id, or (AA, BB..) or (a, b, c,..) or anything
```

How can I do that

Comment: if you using php then you can do it in php or whatever langauge you use

Comment: the idea count how many data returned then create generated `name_i` then assign every value to its generated `name_i`

Comment: Doesn't help you sorry, but for any SQL Server people who find this, the [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) commands can do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12005676/781965) to [another question about the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12004603/781965).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(case when id=1 then name end) as name_1,
        max(case when id=2 then name end) as name_2
From test
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ea68/3)